# Update Existing JQuery Function to Replace "+" With "-" on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery function that I use to animate an accordion-style Q/A on my site. Clicking each blue heading causes answer text to expand into view.

I would like to add additional code so that clicking on the question heading turns the "+" symbol into a "-" symbol (upon answer expansion). When this same heading is clicked to collapse an answer, I would like that same "-" become a "+" symbol once more.

Does anyone know what to add to do this? My current function is below:

```
$(function(){$('.markdown-block .sqs-block-content h2')
    .css('cursor','pointer');

$(".markdown-block .sqs-block-content h2")
    .nextUntil("h2").slideToggle();

$(".markdown-block .sqs-block-content h2")
    .click(function(){$(this).nextUntil("h2").slideToggle()})});
```

HTML pertinent to the Markdown Block, with body text omitted for brevity:

```
<div class="sqs-block markdown-block sqs-block-markdown" data-block-type="44" id="block-yui_3_17_2_6_1466641371234_7523"> = $0
  <div class="sqs-block-content">
    <h2 id="Q/A title" style="cursor: pointer;">_</h2> = $0
    <h2 id="Question-1" style="cursor: pointer;">+Question</h2> = $0
      <h3 id="answer-paragraph-1" style="display: none;">_</h3>
      <h3 id="answer-paragraph-2" style="display: none;">_</h3>
    <h2 id="Question-2" style="cursor: pointer;">+Question</h2> = $0
      <h3 id="answer-paragraph-1" style="display: none;">_</h3>
      <h3 id="answer-paragraph-2" style="display: none;">_</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

That's the basic structure, for every following question.

Thanks!

Comment: please show your html

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after `$(this).nextUntil("h2").slideToggle()`.

Comment: @ewizard , do you want the HTML for the Markdown block? The content within it is what's being toggled on click. Trying to figure out what would be valuable to you and others. The + symbol was typed in as plain text.

Comment: @TheNavigat Semicolons are optional in JavaScript, except in a few cases where the lack of a semicolon could be ambiguous. That code is not ambiguous. However, it's true that the existing code puts semicolons after every statement, so it should add a semicolon after the code you quoted for consistency.

Comment: yah where the symbols are being toggled...nm the answer below looks good

Comment: added the HTML structure into the original question.

Comment: add/remove a class and use css.

Answer (score 1):

If `$(this).nextUntil("h2")` refers to the element that hold your "+"? just add to the on click function something like:

```
$(".markdown-block .sqs-block-content h2").click(function(){
         $(this).nextUntil("h2").slideToggle();
         $(this).nextUntil("h2").text(($(this).nextUntil("h2").text() == "+Question"?"-Question":"+Question"));
        })});
```

Comment: Hey thanks! The "+" is directly part of my h2, all h2 and h3 answer text being included within the markdown block. Would you think h2 would be substituted in there? In any case, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Please add the HTML code, that way I can adapt it to work, or give you an idea of what I would do in that case...

Comment: added the HTML structure into the original question.

Comment: I edited the answer, hope I understood you HTML correctly and the change represents the code you require.